# How to stop one layer going over another

Tags: html, css

I'm having a layer problem where this layer content-3f display over all other layers below it:

```
<div id="content-3f">
            <div id="content-3-1f"><a href="aboutus.aspx"></a></div>
            <div id="content-3-2f"><a href="experiences.aspx"></a></div>
            <div id="content-3-3f"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="line"><hr class="top" /></div>
```

Css:

```
    #content-3f {
        float: left;
        width: 880px;
        height: auto;
        padding: 10px 0px 10px 26px;
        height: 103px;
        clear:both;
    }

    #content-3-1f 
    {
        float: left;
        width: 269px;
        height: 202px;
        margin:0px 20px 0px 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background: url('../images/Guided-tour-logo.png') no-repeat left top;
    }

    #content-3-1f a
    {
        width: 269px;
        height: 202px;
        display:block;
    }

    #content-3-2f 
    {
        float: left;
        width: 269px;
        height: 202px;
        margin:0px 20px 0px 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background: url('../images/Taste-chinatown-logo.png') no-repeat left top;
    }

    #content-3-2f a
    {
        width: 269px;
        height: 202px;
        display:block;
    }

#content-3-3f 
{
    float: left;
    width: 269px;
    height: 202px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: url('../images/Taste-chinatown-logo.png') no-repeat left top;
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

As you see it goes over the `<hr>`

How to fix?

Comment: create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) please

Comment: Is the problem with the yellow line being on top of the 3 boxes?

Comment: yep, and below the line are other layers which those 3 graphic boxes go over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is due to the "float:left" on your #content-3f. The float needs to be cleared for this to work. Here's your solution::

HTML

```
    <div id="content-3f">
        <div id="content-3-1f"><a href="aboutus.aspx"></a></div>
        <div id="content-3-2f"><a href="experiences.aspx"></a></div>
        <div id="content-3-3f"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

      <div class="line"><hr class="top" /></div>  ​
```

Notice the additional div with class "clear" This is used to clear the float in your elements.

Now the CSS

```
#content-3f {
width: 880px;
height: auto;
padding: 10px 0px 10px 26px;
height: 103px;
}
.clear {
clear:both;
}
```

The rest of the css remains the same. Hope this helps.

Yes, I agree with gapple. I guess I didnt study your css properly. its the "height:103px" that's creating the problem. remove that and it works as it is.

But I would like to point out that its always a good idea to clear floats nonetheless.

Comment: Since a height is specified on each of the inner elements, adjusting the height of the outer element to a  corresponding value would achieve the same effect, without requiring a clearing element.

Comment: Ah ha !  its the height in content-3f.  It's smaller than the images hence why.

Comment: @gapple Thanks for pointing that out. Its silly that I didnt see it the first time. I have edited the answer accordingly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to your CSS should give you the answer you are looking for.

```
#content-3-1f, 
#content-3-2f, 
#content-3-3f {
    position:relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Basically `z-index` tells things which "layer" to live on. The default layer is `z-index: 0;`

You also need to specify a relative or absolute position for it to take affect.

Comment: No, that just overlays over the yellow line.  I want the yellow line below the 3 boxes.

Comment: @TeaDrinkingGeek No. It will simply block the yellow line where the other divs are.

Comment: Semantics issue with the original question. "Over" and "Below" are pretty vague.

Answer (score 0):

The more elegant solution is to use `display:inline-block` rather than `float:left` on your boxes.

http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/inline-blocks/